# What is wrong with my div_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can figure out why this simple code would not compile. May be fresh eyes will see what I am missing.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><%=h "Name <Email>" %></th>
    <th>Role</th>
</tr>
<% project.participations.each do |participation| %>
    <tr>
        <%= div_for(participation) do %>
        <td>some stuff</td>
        <td>more stuff</td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I am getting the error

```
compile error
```

/Users/leonid/Documents/rails_apps/appdepot/app/views/projects/_show_participants.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...(( div_for(participation) do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
                              ^
/Users/leonid/Documents/rails_apps/appdepot/app/views/projects/_show_participants.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'
;  end ; @output_buffer.concat "\n\n"
      ^
/Users/leonid/Documents/rails_apps/appdepot/app/views/projects/_show_participants.html.erb:31: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
/Users/leonid/Documents/rails_apps/appdepot/app/views/projects/_show_participants.html.erb:33: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'

Comment: Is `participation` a valid ActiveRecord object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= div_for(participation) do %>
```

should be

```
<% div_for(participation) do %>
```

without the equals sign in front

Comment: <%= div_for %> is valid syntax in Rails 3

Comment: @zetetic: I don't think he's using Rails 3.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Rails 2.3.8 but was looking at documentation for 3.)